# How can I specify an ADF schedule trigger to run twice in a day e.g. at 5:00 AM and 10:30 PM?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Currently - If I specify timings in a schedule trigger - I have to enter hours and minutes separately

e.g. Hours : [05,22]
Minutes : [00,30]

this makes 4 possible combinations of HHmm whereas I would want to run the pipeline only at 0500 and 2230 and not at 0530 and 2200.

How can we achieve this in Azure Data Factory ?

Comment: How about setting up 2 separate triggers, one at 0500 and one at 2230?

Comment: sure can Ray. just wanted to check if there is a way to achieve this. Also thinking of passing it on to Azure UserVoice feedback system

Comment: why adf does not support cron

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @ray. Posting your comment as an answer to help other community members.

@azuresnowflake1 You can create 2 separate triggers, is the only way to run trigger twice in a day. e.g. at 5:00 AM and 10:30 PM.

5.00 AM

[image]

10.30 PM

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes I come across same issue and need to create two trigeer if minutes are different for both trigger.